# Trigger jquery validation plug in error with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, forms, validation

I would like my server side PHP validation on a log in page to trigger an error in the client side jquery validation plug in validation. With non log in forms - structured to use a remote file as an action I just echo back a msg then trigger the client side validation error/success msg based on that returned value. I received some suggestions here before, but they did not work - some syntax errors (or my ignorance) here's some pseudocode:

```
<?php
$username = "foo";
$password = "bar";
if ($_POST['username'] != $username || $_POST['password'] != $password) {
#would like to trigger the #errormsg here
?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
else {
?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>Logged in user sees this content</body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

In my validation script the following:

```
//beginning
success: function(data) {
if (data=="Error") {
$("#Error").html('ERROR MSG HERE').show();
} else {
$("#Success").html('SUCCESS MSG HERE').show();
}
//rules, msgs etc
```

Currently if a user enters the wrong un/pwd it just resets the form, I'd like to tell them the info they entered was wrong. I know PHP can output JS - trying to just do something like in the PHP - but wherever I put that I get some syntax erros due to how the sections are broke up btwn the "} else {:

```
<?php
$username = "foo";
$password = "bar";
if ($_POST['username'] != $username || $_POST['password'] != $password) {
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#Error").html('ERROR MSG HERE').show();
   });
</script>
?>
```

thanks!

Comment: where are you trying to echo out the JS? I don't see that part in your code above.

Comment: Edited the answer - I was just inserting the bottom part in the PHP where I have #would like to trigger the #errormsg here. If I try and insert and echo in the top part it just prints it on page load.thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move your PHP output to the correct section. You can't put a `<script>` element into your HTML page before you even have a doctype or `<html>` tag. It has to go inside the `<head>` or `<body>` section.

```
<?php
$username = "foo";
$password = "bar";

if(!empty($_POST) && $_POST['username'] == $username && $_POST['password'] == $password) {

#display 'LOGGED IN' page here

} else {

   if(!empty($_POST) && ($_POST['username'] != $username || $_POST['password'] != $password)) {
    //Put the javascript error alert here
   }

  //Put the log in form here
}
```

Comment: there must be something wrong with my setup - when I tried just adding an alert where you suggested - it loaded on page load. I need the JS function to only fire if the log in attempt is incorrect...

Comment: Did you check to see if the login attempt IS incorrect? you should do a `print_r($_POST);` and check the values. The fact that you got that alert suggests that the post value don't match the values you defined.

Comment: check it out, un foo pwd bar - http://bit.ly/ngvTnI i have the print in and it just prints it on page load...somehow i'm screwing this up!

Comment: If I enter the correct user name and password, I get logged in as you would expect. Did you keep the JS alert in there for an incorrect login?

Comment: Alert is now back in, it runs on page load. Here's the code in http://codepad.org/gJAieNs4 - somehow I need to trigger the alert/errormsg/js only when incorrect attempt at log in

Comment: Oh ok, Very simple fix for this. Just change your first `if` block to this.

`if(!empty($_POST) && ($_POST['username'] != $username || $_POST['password'] != $password)) { `

You were getting the alert on page load because when someone visit the first time, there is no $_POST['username']. as a result, the alert fires because NULL != $username.

Comment: Thanks Brian! Really appreciate it.

Comment: Hey Brian, added what you have, now it just skips log in and goes straight to the content?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with Ajax Form Submission and server side data validation.
This is the proper way to do it find example below.

### HTML FILE

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javscript" src="latest-jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javscript">

        $(function(){

            $('#login-form').submit(function(){

                $form = $(this);
                $message = $form.find('.message');

                $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(data){

                    if( data.error ) {

                        $message.html( data.message ).removeClass('success').addClass('error');

                    } else if( data.success ) {

                        $message.html( data.message ).removeClass('error').addClass('success');

                    }

                }, 'json');

                return false;
            });

        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="login-form" action="PATH_TO_PHP_FILE" method="post">
        <div class="message"></div>
        <input type="text" name="username" />
        <input type="password" name="password" />
        <input type="submit" value="Login Now !" />
    </form>
</body>
```

### PHP FILE

```
<?php
$username = 'foo';
$password = 'bar';

$response = array('error' => TRUE, 'message' => "Invalid Credentials");

if ( count($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) && $_POST['username'] == $username && $_POST['password'] == $password  ) {

    $response = array('error' => FALSE, 'success' => TRUE, 'message' => "Bingo you have done it !");

}

print json_encode($response); //PHP function to convert array to JSON
exit; //To resolve IE Bug
?>
```

as per my knowledge this is the proper way.

Comment: great stuff! I do run AJAX form submission in other areas, this is just a simple log in no db checks etc..I'm trying to keep this simple and manageable, I just want to show the client their items once logged in from same page. I'll try and rework the thing using your suggestions, appreciated!